# Getting XML element contents without knowing element name PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm currently trying to create a generic PHP class to enable retrieval of XML data. The data all comes in a similar format but will have different element names and sometimes there may be more elements. Example xml:

One feed may show this:

```
<GroupData>
   <Table diff:id="1">
      <Code>1</Code>
      <Name>Red</Name>
      <Type>X</Type>
   </Table>
   <Table diff:id="2">
      <Code>2</Code>
      <Name>Yellow</Name>
      <Type>Y</Type>
   </Table>
</GroupData>
```

Another feed might show:

```
<GroupData>
   <Table diff:id="1">
      <Code>1</Code>
      <Name>Red</Name>
   </Table>
   <Table diff:id="2">
      <Code>2</Code>
      <Name>Yellow</Name>
   </Table>
</GroupData>
```

My PHP looks like this:

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);

$node_list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Table');

for($i=0; $i < $node_list->length; $i++) {

     echo $node_list->item($i)->nodeValue;

}
```

This brings back data, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like it splitting out so I can see the element name and the element value and then create an array out of the data for future use. Is there a way of doing this without using "getElementsByTagName" which is what I have used before to get XML? I know each feed I receive will have Table so I can loop through this each time.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php and use the right selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` looks appropriate. The code should look like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Table');
$data = array();
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $id = $table->getAttribute('id');
    $record = array();
    foreach($table->childNodes as $child) {
        if($child->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $record[$child->nodeName] = $child->nodeValue; 
        }   
    }   
    $data[$id] = $record;
}

var_dump($data);
```

The code creates a multidimensional array where the first dimension's index are the table id's and the second dimension are arrays having key/value pairs from the XML. I've simplified it a little bit and dropped the `diff:` namespace prefixes for this example as they are invalid (not registered) in the snippets you've shown. In the real world code you will need `getAttributeNS('diff', 'id')` instead.

This will give you:

```
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    'Code' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'Name' =>
    string(3) "Red"
    'Type' =>
    string(1) "X"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    'Code' =>
    string(1) "2"
    'Name' =>
    string(6) "Yellow"
    'Type' =>
    string(1) "Y"
  }
}
```

Comment: you are welcome! :) take also care about what did I said about that namespace `diff:`